# Combining proximity criteria within Location Allocation?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network-analyst, proximity, closest-facility, location-allocation

I am using ArcGIS 10.5. 
I will explain the situation first:

There are 134 139 forest centroids that serve as 'Demand point' to source Bioenergy conversion plants in the state of Queensland Australia. There are 24 Existing Bioenergy plants 'Facilities' that 'Require' demand. Finally there are 847 potential new locations for a bioenergy 'Facility' that serve as a 'Candidate' plant.

For my research I want to know how many Forest is being allocated to the 24 existing facilities within 80km radius of each. This can be easily done by the Location Allocation under Network Analist. 
Additionally I want to find which of the 847 can also serve as a facility without taking resource away from the 24 existing facilities or each other.

Therefor I want to select only those facilities out of 847 that are closest to:

- sawmills and towns (points);

  - distribution network and rail (line).

When facilities are within each others 80 km radius I want to select the most feasible one and allocate the resource (forest) to the selected.

Ideally I want to rerun the location allocation network analysis with the 24 existing and a small selection of new facilities (out of the 847 proposed).

Any ideas on how to make a selection withing or outside the location allocation tool.

Comment: How many facilities in total you'd like to have?

Comment: There is no target for that. We only want as many as we need.